# Using DB raw Query in laravel

Tags: laravel

please assist to convert this SQL query into laravel format

```
"update user_names  set assignedTo = '09874',Assigned=1 where timePackage='1 hr' and Assigned=0  order by id limit 1"
```

Comment: What do you mean by "Laravel format"? Do you mean Eloquent?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

DB::table('user_names')
    ->where('timePackage', '1 hr')
    ->where('Assigned', 0)
    ->orderBy('id')
    ->limit(1)
    ->update([
        'assignedTo' => '09874',
        'Assigned' => 1,
    ]);
```

See [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/queries) for more info.

Comment: thanks for the answer. I have adjusted my controller but it is not updating the DB.this is the Controller <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;


class UserNamesController extends Controller
{
public function index()
    {

   DB::table('user_names')
    ->update([
        'assignedTo' => '088',
        'Assigned' => 1,
    ])
    ->where('timePackage', '1 hr')
    ->where('Assigned', 0)
    ->orderBy('id')
    ->limit(1);
}
}

Comment: @user3736334 my bad, you must call `update` at last. edited my answer.

Comment: thanks now I get an error in postman 419 unknown status and no update in db I don't know what am doing wrong.

Comment: thanks alot your code workd I realized the error was because of csrf. issues